# PowerShell Script to pull servers in AD and then search SERVICES running under the Local Administrator account

Tags: powershell, service, active-directory

New to PowerShell, attempting to cobble scripts together to:

1. Pull a list of Servers in Active Directory (done).
2. Query each server for a list of SERVICE accounts running under ADMINISTATOR credentials.

Can anyone guide me...prefer to export out to a CSV file, etc.

THANK YOU!

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Serverlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' `
-Properties Name
Sort-Object -Property Name |
foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
$Server
Get-WmiObject Win32-Service | Select DisplayName, StartName | Where-Object {$_.StartName -eq "administrator"}
```

GETTING THESE ERRORS:

```
At line:5 char:18
+ foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
+                  ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At line:5 char:17
+ foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
+                 ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:5 char:32
+ foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
+                                ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: You have a random `|` at the end of sorting. There's no `|` to your `Sort-Object`. Your loop should be `$ServerList.Name`. You're not passing the computer objects to `Get-WmiObject`, and you're missing the closing brace for your loop.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - THANK YOU.  I've modified the script as follows:

Comment: Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Serverlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' `
-Properties Name
# Sort-Object -Property Name
foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
$ServerList.Name
Get-WmiObject Win32-Service | Select DisplayName, StartName | Where-Object {$_.StartName -eq "administrator"}}

Comment: Looks like it IS getting a list of servers, but then comes with the following error:   
 Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32-Service"
At line:8 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32-Service | Select DisplayName, StartName | Where-O ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Comment: You have a hyphen instead of an underscore for the class. The errors will tell you what you're missing

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have permissions to remotely query those hosts you can try the following:

```bash
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"').DNSHostName
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter "StartName LIKE '%Administrator%'" -ComputerName $computers |
    Select-Object DisplayName, StartName, PSComputerName
```

- Notes
- `Get-CimInstance` and `Get-WmiObject` (replaced in this example, since its no longer maintained in new PowerShell versions) can invoke queries in parallel, hence no loop is required.
- Both cmdlets allow queries with [WQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wql?view=powershell-5.1). Faster filtering this way than with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).
- Only real reason to use `Get-WmiObject` instead of `Get-CimInstance` could be if using DCOM as your remoting protocol. At which point you could use:

  ```bash
  $cimoptions = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol DCOM
  $session = New-CimSession -SessionOption $cimoptions -ComputerName $computers
  Get-CimInstance Win32_Service .... -CimSession $session
  ```

  and connect using a CimSession. Functionality for both cmdlets is mostly the same.
- You should include `PSComputerName` in your `Select-Object` statement to understand from which computer the object is coming from.